# Machine Learning Bayes Statistics

Tags: probability, bayesian, confusion-matrix

I know for all of you reading this, it will be extremely easy, meaning I'm on the right place :)

I'm stuck at Q5. Feel free also to check if my calculations are correct.
Please elaborate in the simplest way possible, I have no prior knowledge to statistics and I understand numerical explanations better than formulas.

[image]

[image]

1. What is the false positive rate at each point.
2. What is the true positive rate at each point.
3. What are then the probabilities of making one or the other of the above mistakes at each point.
4. What is the expected cost of mistakes at each point.
5. Sara has accidentally put a sick and healthy subject (that is hamster) in the same cage. Now she doesn't know which is which. She is going to diagnose both hamsters and administer the cure to the one she believes it is more likely to be sick. Compute is the probability that she will pick the WRONG one.

Comment: The fifth question is not complete. And, it'd be more useful if you could share the question in text since it'd then appear in search results and be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Compute the probability that she`ll pick the WRONG one. My bad for the bad cropping.